# Stripe Cross-Border Payouts Issues

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm hoping that someone here can assist me with this issue. Stripe support has been underwhelming thus far.

We have a Primary Stripe Account setup in the US
We have customers that will be based out of MX that will connect to the US accounts.

From what we understand here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cross-border-payouts there are 2 main criteria that need to occur

1. We need to make these accounts "Custom"
2. We need to use the "recipient" option for the account's service agreement.
3. We also cannot request any other "Capabilities" such as "Card Payments" when setting this up.

Moreover, we have noticed that the moment we use the "Custom" option with Recipient agreement, customers do not have the ability to "Sign In" to their existing Stripe accounts even if they have one. The system always forces them to go through a "new" account setup process. Per Stripe, we are responsible for managing everything including verification of the customer and the customer is NEVER aware of the Stripe account's existence. This has been a hard pill to swallow for some of our larger customers who already have a Stripe account.

Say, we overcome that objection, and say people create new accounts. Now, we're running into a whole new series of problems.

We understand that Stripe requires us to perform separate charges and transfers. Great, we use transfer groups and transfer destination.

However, we also want to use the on_behalf_of parameter so that we attribute the transaction to the connected account for reasons explained here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#on-behalf-of

This is where the fun starts. It appears that if you use on_behalf_of, you cannot use "Automatic Payment Methods".

If you specify "card" as a manual payment method type, it will tell you:

You cannot create a charge with the `on_behalf_of` parameter set to a connected account with `transfers` but without the `card_payments` capability enabled.

However, the kicker is that we cannot request card_payments capability for the custom/restricted accounts. So this is a catch22.

So now, we cannot use On Behalf, and essentially, we're acting as the account of record, which is raising alarms in our accounting department.

In addition to that, our customers want to use OXXO, understandably so. This works fine in DEV mode, but when we enable Production, it tells us:

This payment method (oxxo) is not activated for the account specified in `on_behalf_of`. You can only create testmode oxxo PaymentIntents. You can learn more about this here https://support.stripe.com/questions/i-am-having-trouble-activating-a-payment-method

So, essentially, we are unable to use OXXO w/ or w/o on_behalf.

This makes us think if there are better ways to resolve this issue. We have been trying to get through to Stripe support and their responses have been circular, almost meaningless as they keep pointing us to the documentation and we keep poking holes in their documentation.

Am I missing something here? Looking to see if someone else has had these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-border Payouts as a feature allows US platforms to transfer funds around the world in more countries than Stripe officially in. For example you can accept payments from a customer on your platform and then sends funds to a connected account based in South Africa or South Korea even though Stripe doesn't (at the time of this answer) support those countries for payments.

The overall feature relies on a different type of "agreement" between you and the individual/business you are sending funds to. To do that you have to explicitly set `recipient` as the `service_agreement` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-tos_acceptance-service_agreement).

When you go down that path, you can **not** use `on_behalf_of` at all. Using `on_behalf_of` changes a lot of things such as where the payment is being "made from" which Stripe documents [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#on-behalf-of). For that to happen in South Korea or South Africa, Stripe would have to be able to operate and accept payments there. But they can't, and that's why Cross-border Payouts exist in the first place: to let you send funds in countries where Stripe doesn't yet operate. So not using `on_behalf_of` is entirely expected.

Now, if you don't use `on_behalf_of`, what you are really doing here is accepting payments yourself, on your US account, through the US. So this limits you to the payment method types that Stripe supports for US accounts. This means you can **not** use Oxxo for Mexican customers or Konbini for Japanese one. This is a limitation that Stripe likely will lift over time but it's not available today. For example you can accept a lot of European payment methods from the US now which wasn't possible in 2019. In the future, those things will get easier, it's just not the case now.

What I don't fully understand, is why you would go down that path. You clearly say you don't want to be the "merchant of record", you want to do local acquiring, etc. My read is that you simply want to use Destination charges with `on_behalf_of`. This is supported from US platform to a MX account already. This is something Stripe already supports by default with the "default" services agreement.

While I tried to help with my knowledge, this is really something you have to discuss with Stripe's own support team. They are the only ones that can look at your account details, discuss your business model and understand if they can support you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed response. This is very much appreciated. OXXO integration seems to work on a MXN connected account to US Platform/primary account in test mode. We tested it out thoroughly and rolled it into production, only to find out it doesn't work in LIVE mode. Just an fyi, I just looked at the destination charges, and we are using destination transfers but on_behalf_of will not work with the configuration mentioned. And yes, we have been reaching out to support quite a bit, as I mentioned, but their responsiveness has been slower than expected.

Comment: I have a similar use case. We want customers to buy tickets to webinars offered by foreign instructors through our platform. I found the documentation inadequate, and have not yet found a solution. Stripe support said the following: 
- "Use the `on_behalf_of` parameter to have the charge settle in the connected account's country."
- "cross-border payouts only work with the recipient service agreement"

Comment: @Ned_the_Dolphin this really is a question for Stripe's support, you need to work with them. You're right you can't use `on_behalf_of`. If you use Cross-Border Payouts, you only settle in your platform in the US, that's entirely expected.